# NextJS Jest - locale undefined when testing middleware

Tags: reactjs, next.js, jestjs

NextRequest object is always returning an undefined value for locale data when running it my jest (req.nextUrl.locale)

I'm getting this error when I'm trying to set the value in my test :

```
TypeError: The NextURL configuration includes no locale "en"

    > 101 |     req.nextUrl.locale = 'en';
```

Here is my test :

```
it('should redirect to default locale URL for default locale paths without token', async () => {
    const req = new NextRequest(new Request('https://example.com/register'), {
      headers: {
        locale: 'default',
      },
    });

    req.cookies.set(appConfig.i18n.cookie_locale, 'en');
    req.nextUrl.locale = 'en';

    const response = await middleware(req);

    expect(response).toEqual(
      NextResponse.redirect(new URL('/register', req.url))
    );
  });
```

I tried to set also the header but doesn't change anything

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass in a config object with the right shape as the second parameter to `new NextRequest()`.  In this case, it would look like:

```
const req = new NextRequest(new Request('https://example.com/register'), {
  nextConfig: {
    i18n: {
      defaultLocale: 'en-US',
      locales: ['en-US'],
    },
  },
});
```

Traced via [here](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/blob/77dc763807c31a52278db95a8b71e989d467d95f/packages/next/src/server/web/spec-extension/request.ts#L19), [here](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/blob/77dc763807c31a52278db95a8b71e989d467d95f/packages/next/src/server/web/spec-extension/request.ts#L112), then [here](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/blob/77dc763807c31a52278db95a8b71e989d467d95f/packages/next/src/server/config-shared.ts#L22)